# Magento 2 product page include custom phtml file before reviews section

Tags: magento2, layout, custom, page-layouts

Can anyone help me how to include custom phtml file before reviews section in magento2

please find the screenshot below:

[image]

When i click on the button it is going to add to cart.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below code In catalog_product_view.xml in your theme

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                             
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customblock" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom.phtml" before="product.info.review"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks @VDC it is coming after the addtocart section

Comment: OK so your review from is showing in Tab and you want to show this in Review Tab under review from right ?

Comment: no problem with the place of the button but when i click on it, product is going to add to cart

Comment: Please find the updated question

Comment: in your custom button code don't use button type="submit" as place of use button type="button"

Comment: iam using like this: <button class="btn btn-info share-btn">Share</button>

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-info share-btn">Share</button>

Comment: use above updated code

Comment: Thanks a lot @vdc its working now, you saved my day.

Comment: its my pleasure :)

Comment: Hi @vdc iam also getting the following errors: TypeError: a is undefined[Learn More]

Comment: In minicart added product is not displaying

Comment: for JS error look like your function is not defined and for minicart please make sure your product visibility set as Catalog, Search

Comment: Yes previously it is worked